# Html attribute control with if

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my img has 3 attribute but if has one attribute (`data-web-src`,`data-tablet-src`,`data-mobil-src`) than set my src than one of them attribute is that possible ?

[please click to see on codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/bqNoZz)

```js
function noLazyImages(e) {
  $(e + '.lazy_res').attr('src', function(_, oldSrc) {
    var elData = $(this).data(),
      winWidth = $(window).width();
    if (winWidth >= 768 && winWidth < 960) {
      return elData['webSrc']
    } else if (winWidth < 768 && winWidth >= 480) {
      return elData['tabletSrc']
    } else if (winWidth < 480) {
      return elData['mobilSrc']
    } else if (winWidth > 960) {
      return elData['webSrc']
    }
  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  noLazyImages("body img");
})
```

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/bdf1d94b64104ef2acd2ceee19882cd1.jpg" data-mobil-src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/caa51ab4900448589201207e57b2630f.jpg" data-tablet-src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/4b2862a292b543139daa7805a58c17fd.jpg"
/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I posted an answer from what i understood from your question. Now you have edited the question and it is more unclear to understand what you are really trying to do. Can you make the question more clear?

Comment: my img has 3 attribute and my src value is empty..if I'm on desktop than get value of `data-web-src` and set for src but if I'm on tablet than get value of `data-web-tablet` and set src but if my img has only one attribute (for example just: `data-web-src`) than get it and use both on desktop,tablet and mobil (sorry my english is not enought to explain something)

Comment: You explained it very well in this comment! I suggest you add this explanation to the question as well so that it is easier for others looking for similar answer :)

Comment: hahaha..sorry about it as I sad my english is not enough sorry that is wht :))

Comment: and I will go to the english course soon :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code will do what you want.

I removed the `data-tablet-src` from the `img` tag which is there in the question snippet so that you can run both and compare the results.

**Logic**

`if(elData['tabletSrc'])` will be false if `elData['tabletSrc']` is not present. So it will return `return elData['webSrc']` instead.

```js
function noLazyImages(e) {
  $(e + '.lazy_res').attr('src', function(_, oldSrc) {
    var elData = $(this).data(),
      winWidth = $(window).width();
    if (winWidth < 768 && winWidth >= 480) {
     if(elData['tabletSrc']){
       return elData['tabletSrc'];
      }
    } else if (winWidth < 480) {
      if(elData['mobilSrc']){
       return elData['mobilSrc'];
      }
    }
    return elData['webSrc'];
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  noLazyImages("body img");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/bdf1d94b64104ef2acd2ceee19882cd1.jpg" data-mobil-src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/caa51ab4900448589201207e57b2630f.jpg"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script work fine you just need to add listener to window resize event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  noLazyImages("body img"); // on Document ready

  $( window ).resize(function() {
    noLazyImages("body img"); // on window Resize
  });

})
```

Comment: do I have to remove on document.ready ? is it enough for window.resize ?

Comment: No, you need to trigger the function once to set the correct image for the current viewport width. and then you attach the event so the image will be change due any window resize event.